# Asking a truth question without specifying a denomination

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

> Bad: Is Michael the Archangel also Jesus?
>
> There are at least two answers to this question. Which one is right? We don't know. We can't handle the Truth.
>
> Good: Do Jehovah's Witnesses believe Michael the Archangel is Jesus?
>
> There is only one answer, because the question is no longer asking for truth, but only what a specific group of Christians believe. Jehovah's Witnesses have a well-defined answer to this question.

Ok, so you can convert a truth question into a question that's on-topic for Christianity.SE by asking about a specific denomination.

What if I want an answer that's an average of all the major denominations' viewpoints? Or how about 1 answer per denomination?

I asked [Does talking about other gods go against the 1st commandment?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/65654/30731) and it was put on hold. How do I make my question on-topic without specifying a denomination?